# Can't get checkbox value in datagrid ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a DataGrid which has Checkboxes which are used to select certain users. When Ok button is clicked, I should get the state of checkbox, and if checked get ID of the row. I get to the checkbox, but value is always Checked = false, even when I check my checkbox, of course. Code is below:

.aspx

```
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Odabir">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkVjezba" runat="server" Enabled="true"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>

            <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Vježba" DataField="Naziv"></asp:BoundColumn>

            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Broj serija">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="brojSerija" runat="server" Width="20px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>

            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Ocjena 6">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ocjena6" runat="server" Width="20px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>

            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Ocjena 7">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ocjena7" runat="server" Width="20px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>

            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Ocjena 8">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ocjena8" runat="server" Width="20px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>

            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Ocjena 9">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ocjena9" runat="server" Width="20px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>

            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Ocjena 10">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ocjena10" runat="server" Width="20px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>

    </asp:DataGrid>
```

My .cs Code File:

```
foreach (DataGridItem row in vjezbeGrid.Items)
            {
            if (((CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkVjezba")).Checked)
            {
               //something
            }

        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might databind on every postback. Make sure that you databind only if !Page.IsPostBack.

Comment: That's it! Great. I've just added on pageload event if(!IsPostBack)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
foreach (DataGridItem row in vjezbeGrid.Items)
        {
            if (row.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                CheckBox chkVjezba = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkVjezba");

                if (chkVjezba.Checked)
                {
                    //something
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the if(!isPostBack) to the pageLoad event solved the problem.

Comment: @rukfash Don't forgot to mark as answer.whose answer is better helpful to you